# unable to connect to remote server c# while sending mail

Tags: c#, .net, email, io, html-email

I am currently trying to send an email through System.Net.Mail.MailMessage but as I run my code, I generate this exception, Failure sending mail. The inner exception is: unable to connect to remote server. I believe I am connecting to the remote server but am curious to why I get this exception
Here is how my code looks:

```
 try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

            msg.Subject = "Testing Email";

            msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@gmail.com");

            msg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("isavepluscom@gmail.com"));

            msg.Body = "testing the email";



            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smpt = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

            smpt.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            smpt.Port = 587;

            smpt.EnableSsl = true;

            smpt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@gmail.com", "1234567890");

            smpt.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Do I need to have anything inside my webconfig file even though I set the credentials in the code?

Comment: try replacing this line `msg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("isavepluscom@gmail.com"));` with the following msg.To.Add("isavepluscom@gmail.com");` also replace this line `msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@gmail.com");` with `msg.From = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com");`

Comment: no this did not work, it still gives me the error: unable to connect to remote server

Comment: what Port does `Gmail` expect to receive it's credentials on.. ? also do you have an account setup on gmail named `test` along with that exact password..? hopefully you are replacing it with the correct credentials

Comment: I am sure it is 587, yes I replace it with my own, its for security that I place a fake on here

Comment: Look at my answer, I just tested this working with my own Gmail Account / Password.. much easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try shortening your code to something like the following

```
 var smptClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 {
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("isavepluscom@gmail.com", "123456789"),
     EnableSsl = true
 };
  smptClient.Send("isavepluscom@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com", "Testing Email", "testing the email");
```

Comment: I see what you did, but the problem persists, it might be my servers firewall which is blocking the connection, I will play around with it to see

Comment: that could be the case, however the code does works on my end testing with my own account on our network. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look like a security exception. Make sure port 587 is opened for communication, if it is a server i will be blocked by default.